# Implement the 'zip' with continuation in C++

Tags: c++, templates, functional-programming

I'm trying to write a demo to implement Haskell's `zip` function with `continuation` in C++, and I've implemented the `fmap` and `take` followed the [Yakk - Adam Nevraumont's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65345054/eliminate-redundant-template-argument-in-c/65345492#65345492). My code looks like this:

```
template <typename Upstream, typename Other, typename Zip>
struct F_zip;

template <typename T>
struct F {
  template <typename Other, typename Zip>
  F_zip<T, Other, Zip> zip(const Other& other, const Zip& z) const {
    return {*static_cast<T const*>(this), other, z};
  }
};

template <typename X>
struct F_id : F<F_id<X>> {
  const X x;

  F_id(const X& x) : x(x) {}

  template <typename Callback>
  void operator()(Callback&& callback) const { callback(x); }
};

template <typename Upstream, typename Other, typename Zip>
struct F_zip : F<F_zip<Upstream, Other, Zip>> {
  Upstream upstream;
  Other other;
  Zip zip;

  F_zip(const Upstream& upstream, const Other& other, const Zip& zip)
      : upstream(upstream),
        other(other),
        zip(zip) {}

  template <typename Callback>
  void operator()(Callback&& callback) const {
    upstream([=](auto a) {
      other([=, &a](auto b) {
        callback(zip(a, b));
      });
    });
  }
};

void test_zip() {
  F_id(10)
    .zip(F_id(20), [](int x, int y) { return std::make_tuple(x, y); })([](atuo x) {
      auto [a, b] = x;
      printf("(%d, %d)\n", a, b);
    });
}
```

The code works fine, but I want the `upstream` and `other` run "in parallel", just like:

```
? a;
? b;
bool is_a_present, is_b_present;

template <typename Callback>
void operator()(Callback&& callback) {
  upstream([=, &a, &b, &is_a_present, &is_b_present](auto x) {
    a = x;
    is_a_present = true;
    if (is_b_present) callback(zip(a, b));
  });
  other([=, &a, &b, &is_a_present, &is_b_present](auto x)) {
    b = x;
    is_b_present = true;
    if (is_a_present) callback(zip(a, b));
  }
}
```

I've tried to add template arguments to declare the type of `a`/`b` or use `void*` to store `a`/`b` but all failed.

Any idea?